# Slice and fill 2d array with 1d array of column indices

Tags: python, numpy

Firstly, here's the 1-d analog of what I'm trying to do..

Suppose I have a 1d array of 0s and I want to replace every 0 from index 2 onward with a 1. I can do this as follows:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,0,0])
i = 2
x[i:] = 1
print(x)  # [0 0 1 1]
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out the 2d version of this operation. To start, I have a 5x4 array of 0s like

```
foo = np.zeros(shape = (5,4))

[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

and a corresponding 5 element array of column indices like

```
fill_locs = np.array([0, 3, 1, 1, 2])
```

For each row of foo, I want to fill columns `i:` with 1s where `i` is the index given by `fill_locs`. `foo[fill_locs.reshape(-1, 1):] = 1` feels right, but doesn't work.

My desired output should look like

```
expected_result = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need slicing, and you don't need to create the original array.  You can accomplish all of this with broadcasted comparison.

---

```
a = np.array([0, 3, 1, 1, 2])
n = 4

(a[:, None] <= np.arange(n)).view('i1')
```

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

---

Or using `less_equal.outer`

```
np.less_equal.outer(a, np.arange(n)).view('i1')
```